# How to shift all the whole numbers in a double to the right of the point

Tags: c#, math, double

How to shift all the whole numbers in a double to the right of the point ?
Example i have 5342, i want the function to return 0.5342. I do not know the number of digits in the double, it's randomly generated. Should be fairly easy but i can't find any answers.

Comment: `double someNumber = Convert.ToDouble("0." + 5321, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` , **but don't** :)

Comment: @Habib Can that handle negatives?

Comment: yeah that's why I said , don't :P

Comment: what about dividing your number by 10000 (the number of 0s you'd like here)

Comment: Does the double always contain an integer value reasonably small? Floating point numbers like doubles don't hold exact numbers above or below a certain point - hence the floating point!

Comment: @Lukos: Well they always hold exact numbers - it's just that it might not be exactly equal to the original source. (For example, `double d = 0.1;` assigns an exact value to `d`, but it's not exactly 0.1.)

Answer (score 3):

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(MyFunction(5127));
    Console.WriteLine(MyFunction(1));
    Console.WriteLine(MyFunction(51283271));
    Console.WriteLine(MyFunction(-512));
    Console.WriteLine(MyFunction(0));
}

    public static double MyFunction(double myNumber)
    {
        return Math.Floor(myNumber) / Math.Pow(10, Math.Abs(myNumber).ToString().Length);
    }
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Ran it in .NET Fiddle; it works now. THanks for fixing! (might want to update your output... Heres the fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7glnL5

Comment: Thanks for fixing my solution.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a pretty bizarre task, to be honest,  but you could use:

```
while (Math.Abs(value) >= 1)
{
    value = value / 10;
}
```

That will go into an infinite loop if the input is infinity though - and you may well lose information as you keep dividing. The latter point is important - if what you're really interested in is the decimal representation, you should consider using `decimal` instead of `double`.

You could *potentially* use a mixture of `Math.Log` and `Math.Pow` to do it, but the above is probably what I'd start with.

Answer (score 0):

Just divide by 10 until the number is less than 1.

```
public static double SomeMethod(double n)
{
    double d = n;
    bool isNegative = (d < 0);
    if(isNegative)
        d = d * -1;

    while(d >= 1)
        d = d/10;

    if(isNegative)
        d = d * -1;

    return d;
}
```

Alternative (and more precise) option:

```
public static double SomeMethod2(double n)
{
    double d = n;
    bool isNegative = (d < 0);
    if(isNegative)
        d = d * -1;

    int numberOfDigits = ((int)d).ToString().Length;

    int divisor = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfDigits; i++)
        divisor = divisor * 10;

    d = d/divisor;

    if(isNegative)
        d = d * -1;

    return d;
}
```

Comment: This can lose precision every time you divide so the result will not necessarily be correct. It depends on the domain of input values and the need for them to be accurately "shifted"

Comment: @Lukos Updated with better alternative solution

Answer (score 0):

This will get you most of the way there

```
    public static string test()
    {
        double dub = 5432;

        string dubTxt = dub.ToString();

        string text = "0.";

        string test = string.Concat(text + dubTxt);

        if (1 == 1)
        {

           MessageBox.Show(test);
           return test;

        }
    }
```

You will have to develop more if statements to handle the negative numbers.

```
    public static string test()
    {
        double dub = 5432;

        string dubTxt = dub.ToString();

        string text = "0.";

        string test = string.Concat(text + dubTxt);

        if (dub < 0)
        {

              //Do this code instead
        }
    }
```

Good Luck. Please bump me if you choose it!! I need the cred so I can do other junk. :-D